# Elastic Nest Html Strip on Automapp

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Hopefully a quick one I am automapping my Index and I just want to universally strip html from any field is this possible I have tried this

```
var des = new CreateIndexDescriptor("myindex")
            .Settings(s =>s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .CharFilters(c => c.HtmlStrip("product"))))
            .Mappings(ms => ms
            .Map<Product>(m => m
            .Properties(ps => ps
                .Nested<ProductSpecification>(n => n
                    .Name(c => c.ProductSpecification)
                    .Properties(psp => psp
                        .Keyword(s => s
                            .Name(ps1 => ps1.Name)
                        )
                        .Keyword(s => s
                            .Name(ps1 => ps1.Value)
                        )
                    )
                )
                ).AutoMap()
            ));
```

Comment: Character filters need to be applied to an analyzer and that analyzer will need to be applied to the entire document I think. See example configuration here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html

Comment: Please post a succinct example that includes relevant details e.g. what do `Product` and `ProductSpecification` look like?